# What is the comparative form of the adverb "nicely"?

Tags: adverbs, comparatives, morphology, superlative-degree

The adjective *nice* can be inflected: *nicer, nicest*. Can the derived adverb *nicely* be inflected as well, or does it only have the absolute form?

Comment: No, people would think you were soft in the head if you came out with, for example, *nicelier*. I suppose I could have phrased things *more nicely* - but to be honest, even that seems slightly clunky to me. I'd just use *nicer* for all contexts and be done with it.

Comment: ...having said that, [**"quicklier"** does exist](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quicklier&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquicklier%3B%2Cc0) (but it's going *out* of fashion, not coming in).

Comment: If you spoke Early Modern English, you would probably say *nicelier, nicer, more nicely, more nice* or even *more nicelier* or *more nicer.*  Considering that you speak Modern English, however, I advise that you use *more nicely* as your default form and *nicer* only in colloquial settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wikitionary, "more nicely" is the comparative form.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nicely

Answer (score 0):

There is a grammar rule in English that adverbs in -ly and participles have forms of comparison with "more" and "most". There are some adverbs with forms of comparison in -er/-est as early, earlier, earliest.
The Longman English Grammar by L. G. Alexander has "The comparison of adverbs" in paragraph 7.4.

Comment: Only adverbs transparently formed by adding _-ly_ to the stem are blocked from morphological comparison. _Early_ (which is also the adjective) is not transparently formed from an adjective _ear_, which is why it is an apparent exception.